Why are ASCII escape sequences for ' treated differently in grep/sed/awk?
Using the GNU version of all 3 tools (scroll down for FreeBSD attempts), if I wanted to find ' in input using awk with a '-delimited script we can try matching using the hex and octal escape sequences:
$ echo "'" | awk '/\x27/'
'

$ echo "'" | awk '/\047/'
'

$ echo "'" | awk '/\o047/'
awk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\o' is not a known regexp operator

so the first 2 work and the 3rd doesn't, as you'd intuitively expect.
Now let's try the same with sed (with or without -E):
$ echo "'" | sed -n '/\x27/p'
'

$ echo "'" | sed -n '/\047/p'
$

$ echo "'" | sed -n '/\o047/p'
'

and grep (also with or without -E):
$ echo "'" | grep '\x27'
grep: warning: stray \ before x

$ echo "'" | grep '\047'
grep: warning: stray \ before 0

$ echo "'" | grep '\o047'
grep: warning: stray \ before o

So:

Most importantly: why are they different?
Secondary curiosity: Is there a way to use an escape sequence in grep to match ' without resorting to GNU greps non-portable -P option and without expanding the escape sequence before grep sees it using shell constructs such as grep $'\047'?

It's worth noting that octal \047 is the recommended escape sequence in awk (see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote, or https://web.archive.org/web/20230530010453/http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote if that's down).
For the purposes of this question I'm not interested in alternatives that allow literal ' or what any other tools do or anything else, I'm just trying to find out why those 3 specific regexp-matching tools treat ASCII escape sequences differently from each other. I would, however, be interested in learning how BSD or other variants of those 3 tools behave given the same scripts shown above.
Additional Information:
FreeBSD
This is FreeBSD 13.1 behavior:
% echo "'" | awk '/\x27/'
'
% echo "'" | awk '/\047/'
'
% echo "'" | sed -n '/\x27/p'
'
% echo "'" | sed -n '/\047/p'
% echo "'" | sed -n '/\o047/p'
sed: 1: "/\o047/p": RE error: trailing backslash (\)
% echo "'" | grep '\x27'
grep: trailing backslash (\)
% echo "'" | grep '\047'
% 

POSIX
Here's what the POSIX standards for Regular Expressions and the 3 tools in question say about this:

regexps: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html
awk:
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/utilities/awk.html
sed:
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/utilities/sed.html
grep:
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/utilities/grep.html

From the regexp spec we see that neither x nor 0 are "Special Characters" in a BRE or ERE so therefore they are "Ordinary Characters" and that

When not inside a bracket expression, the interpretation of an
ordinary character preceded by an unescaped <backslash> is undefined,
except for:

followed by lists of characters, none of which includes 0 or x for BREs or EREs so my conclusion from that is that neither \x27 nor \047 are defined behavior in a regexp per POSIX.
The POSIX awk spec Regular Expressions section says:

\ddd
A <backslash> character followed by the longest sequence of
one, two, or three octal-digit characters (01234567). If all of the
digits are 0 (that is, representation of the NUL character), the
behavior is undefined. If the digits produce a value greater than
octal 377, the behavior is undefined.

so we know that \0 is defined for a POSIX awk but \x is not, so the awk behavior for \x is undefined by POSIX for awk and therefore is left up to the various awk implementations.
The POSIX sed spec Regular Expressions section adds a couple of twists to regexp but doesn't mention \0 or \x and defers to the POSIX regexp definitions and so \0 or \x are undefined by POSIX for sed.
The POSIX grep spec Description section defers entirely to the POSIX regexp definitions and so \0 or \x are undefined by POSIX for grep.
So apparently the meaning of \xdd is left up to the tool implementers for grep, sed, and awk, while the meaning of \0dd is defined for awk but left up to the implementers for grep and sed.
GNU Manuals
The GNU awk manual Escape Sequences section says:

\nnn
The octal value nnn, where nnn stands for 1 to 3 digits between ‘0’ and ‘7’. For example, the code for the ASCII ESC (escape)
character is ‘\033’.
\xhh…
The hexadecimal value hh, where hh stands for a sequence of hexadecimal digits (‘0’–‘9’, and either ‘A’–‘F’ or ‘a’–‘f’). A maximum
of two digits are allowed after the ‘\x’...

so that's where \x47 is defined for GNU awk.
The GNU sed manual Escape Sequences section says:

\oxxx
Produces or matches a character whose octal ASCII value is xxx.
\xxx
Produces or matches a character whose hexadecimal ASCII value is xx.

so that's where \o047 and \x27 are defined for GNU sed.
The GNU grep manual has no references I could find to either hex or octal escape sequences which explains the warning messages we see when we try to use them and presumably means they simply aren't supported in GNU grep.

Note that in the case of FreeBSD sed, the \xHH are not handled by the regexp engine, but are instead expanded before being passed to the regexp engine. For instance, echo x | sed '/\x2e/!d' outputs x because the regexp engine sees just . (assuming an ASCII-based system), same as if you had run sed '/./!d'

You're definitely not going to get anywhere looking for \u, \x, or any kind of charcode escapes in grep. In the manual you linked to, not only does the "Matching Non-ASCII and Non-printable Characters" section recommend feeding unprintable/untypeable characters in as part of a pattern via $'\xXX' and $'\uXXXX' escapes, but the script-safer, more portable alternative they offer to that is grep "$(printf '\xXX and/or \uXXXX')"! A between-the-lines reading makes it pretty clear there's just no interest in having grep itself support charcode-escapes.

\1, \2, \3, \4... are used for back-references in basic regular expressions (BRE from the late 60s as found in ed, grep, sed...). For instance:
$ grep -ix '\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\).\4\3\2\1' /usr/share/dict/words
Malayalam

To find 9 letter palindromes (not 5 characters followed by ^D^C^B^A).
Extended regexps (ERE) introduced with egrep in the late 70s with a new regexp algorithm did not have (and could not have with that algorithm) back reference support.
awk contemporary to egrep, with a language shaped after that of C used EREs from the start, had C-like string literals inside which you could have \47 octal escapes (like in C), and there was nothing stopping those escapes also being added in the /ERE/ regexp literals since EREs could not have back references.
Outside of awk, neither POSIX BRE not ERE support those escapes. Only \n is specified for sed (as it was historically supported by the original sed).
\47 as an escape sequence for byte 0x27 can definitely not be added to BREs as it would clash with back references. As many ERE implementations have added support for back-references since the late 70s, adding it to ERE is no longer an option either. It's a pain that most awk don't support back-references and in those that do such as busybox's, you have to do awk '$0 ~ "^(.*)\\1$"' for the equivalent of grep -x '\(.*\)\1' (not awk '/^(.*)\1$/' as that \1 is ^A instead and awk '/^(.*)\\1$/' is to match on something that ends in \1).
Note that the syntax in every tool but echo for those octal sequences (initially possibly from C) is \ followed by 1 to 3 octal numbers, there's no requirement for a leading 0 and you can't have a leading 0 for byte numbers above 63 (077). (\0377 in anything but echo is \037 (^_) followed by 7), so while \047 doesn't clash with back-references as \0 is not a valid back-reference (in POSIX BRE at least, there are some where \0 means the whole match), \377 would.
The \xHH is from C89 (ANSI C), also found in perl since perl 4 (in its string literals and regexp literals there). It doesn't have that clashing problem with back-references but is not supported by all regexp engines yet³. In C, \x can be followed by any number of hex digits as chars in ANSI C don't have to be 8 bit. In perl, only up to 2 digits are accepted, though \x{HH} which can be extended to \x{20AC}¹ when in Unicode mode is also supported. Elsewhere, how many hex digits may be consumed after \x varies with the application. For instance in ksh93, $'\x20AC' is not byte 0x20 (space in ASCII) followed by AC, but character U+20AC (€), UTF-8 encoded².
The $'\47' and $'\x27' shell quoting operators from ksh93 are now in POSIX sh since the 2024 edition of the standard (not in all sh implementations yet; in particular, not dash as found on most Debian-based systems).
in any case, like awk's "\47" (or $'\x27'4), that expands to byte 0x27, so only to ' on systems that use ASCII as their base charset, so that's one I refrain from using myself as I don't see the point in introducing a dependency on a particular character encoding.
The $'\u0027' (or $'\u27' or $'\U00000027') from zsh which does expand to the ' character almost made it to POSIX 2024 for sh as well, but as there were some disagreements and differences between shells as to what charset those should expand to (UTF-8 unconditionally à la ksh93, the locale's charmap at the time the code is read à la bash, the locale's charmap at the time it is executed à la zsh) and what to do when the charmap doesn't have the corresponding character, its inclusion was postponed to the next major version.
In any case for ' specifically, there's no need to specify the point code, as \' can be used within $'...' to represent a single quote.
With those \OOO and \xHH now added to sh, there's even less reason for each individual tool to add support for them.
My own preferred way to embed ' inside a sed, awk, perl, sh single-quoted code argument, or any single-quoted argument to any command for that matters, in POSIX-like shells is to insert it as \' outside the single quotes:
sh -c 'echo "It'\''s not pretty, but it works"'
awk 'BEGIN{print "It'\''s not pretty, but it works"}'

With awk, you can do:
awk -v q="'" 'BEGIN{print "It" q "s not really prettier"}'

In rc or zsh -o rcquotes
awk 'BEGIN{print "It''s slightly prettier"}'

In fish, you can do:
awk 'BEGIN{print "It\'s slightly prettier"}'

But that means '...' are not fully strong quotes there, so, like for ksh93's $'...', you have to watch for \ inside which is a pain.
Another option is to do:
awk_code=$(cat << 'EOF'
BEGIN {print "It's much more legible albeit a bit longer"}
EOF
)
awk "$awk_code"


¹ Even \x{7fffffffffffffff} going way beyond the Unicode range, extending the UTF-8 encoding algorithm.
² while $'\xe9' expands to byte 0xe9, not the UTF-8 encoding of U+00E9 (é). That matches the perl behaviour in this default non-Unicode mode where the default encoding is iso8859-1 (aka latin1, single-byte) where characters above 255 don't exist so perl switches to UTF-8 for those (and issues a warning), but in perl when in Unicode mode, "\xe9" expands to the UTF-8 encoding of U+00E9, while in ksh93, $'\xe9' is byte 0xe9 regardless of whether in a UTF-8 locale or not. To output UTF-8 encoded characters based on their Unicode code point, it's better to use the newer (from zsh) \uXXXX (or \UXXXXXXXXX for those code points above 0xffff)
³ In the case of GNU and FreeBSD sed that you mention, it's not done by the regexp engine; those \xHHs are expanded (in various places, not just regexps) before calling the regexp engines (similar to what happens if you do $0 ~ "\47" instead of /\47/ in standard awk or $_ =~ "\x27" instead of /\x27/ in perl), in the case of GNU sed added in 1998 (and \dDDD and \oOOO soon after in 1999) and for FreeBSD only since 13.0 (commit).
4 though beware that one has to make sure that what follows is not more hexadecimal digits as ksh93's behaviour there $'\x20ac' expands to € as mentioned above is allowed though not required by POSIX, so if you want byte 0x27 followed by AC, you need $'\x27'$'AC' for instance (or use the octal form that doesn't have the problem; ksh93 does support $'\x{27}AC' but that one has not been specified by POSIX and as mentioned rarely found.

Thanks for the answer, I'll read it in detail a little later but regarding "In any case for ' specifically, there's no need to specify the point code, as $''' works." - I use \047 in my scripts so they will work whether I use them from the command line as awk 'foo \047 bar' or stored in a file as awk -f scriptfile and you can't do that if you write the script as foo '\'' bar instead.

@EdMorton, in what sort of context would that be an actual problem? It's the same in sh -c 'echo "It'\''s not pretty, but it works"' vs having echo "It's not pretty, but it works" in a shell script.

I'm not sure what you mean. I'll fairly often start writing a script (actually a utility awk function) as awk 'BEGIN{print "It\047s not pretty"}' and then as it grows decide I should move it to a file foo.awk containing BEGIN{print "It\047s not pretty"} to execute as awk -f foo.awk or vice-versa. If my starting point was instead awk 'BEGIN{print "It'\''s not pretty"}' then I couldn't save BEGIN{print "It'\''s not pretty"} to a file foo.awk and execute it as awk -f foo.awk.

@EdMorton, you can always replace awk with printf '%s\n' > file.awk to store that awk code, same as you'd do for sh, sed code or anything else.

Then I'd have to do printf '%q' or something to go the other way. Copy/paste is simpler and \047 works in both contexts.

Regarding awk_code=$(here doc); awk "$awk_code" - I think that's the first time I've seen awk code stored in a variable where it was a useful thing to do. Until now I've thought it was just to help syntax highlighting of shell scripts in some editors.

So.... after doing some wading through POSIX and reading your answer, am I right in thinking that \027 and \27 are both undefined behavior per POSIX for all 3 of grep, sed and awk and that \x47 is defined by POSIX for awk but undefined for grep and sed? I added the standards references to the bottom of my question, if you know of anywhere else in POSIX that those escape sequences are defined for those tools, please let me know.

@EdMorton, that's the other way round \x27 is not defined for anything other than $'...', \47 for C, awk, printf format (both of which are shaped after C), and \047 for echo and printf's %b.

You're right, I got it backwards (been doing that all day and correcting!). Thanks for confirming.

Stéphane and I have had this conversation before, but "\x27" is also valid in perl, which is where I use it for this kind of thing:  BEGIN { $q = "\x27" }

@jrw32982 I do mention it already here: also found in perl since perl 4; one of the earliest tools to support it (and \x{ffff...} before C added \uFFFF I believe which I mention as well).
